# Update master CSV with unique rows from multiple files

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I need to maintain a master CSV file (child file) that is populated from distinct rows in multiple other files (parent files).  All parent files have the same layout.  The child file will have 2 additional columns appended at the end (Columns for filename[where the data came from] and time[when the append was made]).

*Edit: Updated Code:

```
import glob, os, csv, time


DI = 'E:\Python\Test\MergeFilesIn'
FO = 'E:\Python\Test\MergeFilesOut\Export.txt'

olddata = set()
with open(FO) as master:
    for row in enumerate(csv.reader(master, delimiter = '|')):
        key = '|'.join(row[:3])
        olddata.add(key)

data = []

for input_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(DI, '*.txt')):
    with open(input_file) as finput:
        for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(finput, delimiter = '|')):
            key = '|'.join(row)
            if key not in olddata:
                to_append = "Filename" if i==0 else input_file
                data.append(row+[to_append])
                olddata.add(key)
    print(data)
with open(FO, 'w') as foutput:
    for key in olddata:
        foutput.write(key + '\n')
```

This code will merge all the data from the files in the 'DI' folder and append the filename to the export file. Currently, headers are also copied.

What i need the code to do: Update master file with unseen records (distinct in even one column) from all parent files, ignoring headers.  I think the key lies in loading all the parent files into a list(or dict?) and then comparing that to the child list and taking only the difference - this is what I was hoping to start accomplishing with the olddata = [] part, but I got lost trying to figure out how to compare that to data = []. Order of rows (with the exception of the header) doesn't matter.

Example of how the program should work:

```
if export file = 

    header1|header2|header3|filename|timestamp

and parent files =

File1:
    header1|header2|header3|
    apple|banana|strawberry

File2:
    header1|header2|header3|
    apple|banana|blueberry

File3:
    header1|header2|header3|
    apple|banana|strawberry
    pineapple|kiwi|blackberry

Run program, exportfile=

    header1|header2|header3|filename|timestamp
    apple|banana|strawberry|file1|0600
    apple|banana|blueberry|file2|0600
    pineapple|kiwi|blackberry|file3|0600

Add new parent file:
File4:
    header1|header2|header3|
    apple|banana|strawberry
    pineapple|kiwi|blackberry
    cats|dogs|birds

Run program, exportfile=

    header1|header2|header3|filename|timestamp
    apple|banana|strawberry|file1|0600
    apple|banana|blueberry|file2|0600
    pineapple|kiwi|blackberry|file3|0600
    cats|dogs|birds|file4|0700
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have any actual data to test, but I think the proposed solutions all have one problem in common, they all try to keep the data in memory. If your master file grows sufficiently large, you might run into problems with that. I would go with checksums.

```
import csv
import time
import glob
import hashlib

MASTER_FILE = "master.csv" # replace with a real name


def checksum(msg):
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    hasher.update(str(msg).encode())
    return hasher.digest()


def unique_line(line, masterdata):
    return checksum(line) not in masterdata


def append_to_master(line, filename, master_filename):
    with open(master_filename, 'a') as master:
        csv.writer(master).writerow(line + [filename, time.ctime()])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # load master file data
    masterdata = []
    with open(MASTER_FILE, 'r') as master:
        reader = csv.reader(master)
        reader.next() # skip header
        masterdata = [checksum(line[:-2]) for line in reader] # skip the last two fields containing time stamp and file name
    # process new data
    files_to_process = glob.glob("*.csv") # replace with a real pattern
    for filename in files_to_process:
        with open(filename, 'r') as data:
            reader = csv.reader(data)
            reader.next() # skip header
            for line in reader:
                if unique_line(line, masterdata):
                    append_to_master(line, filename, MASTER_FILE)
```

Comment: Line 26ish: __reader.next()__ is returning an error for me: __'_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'__.  I modified the code to reader.\__next\__() and got the error message __StopIteration__.  I then tried next(reader) and got the same __StopIteration__ error.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this off the top of my head, so mistakes have been made. next(reader) should be correct. If you are getting an error it means some file doesn't have any lines in it, while my code expects it to have at least a row of headers. You can add default value to the next() call to prevent getting the error next(reader, None)

Comment: I see.  It was my blank header row.  I just copied a header into it.  Program runs now, but duplicate rows (The same row between files) are included.  E.G. if file1 has row: a|b|c and file2 has row: a|b|c, then masterfile has a|b|c|file1|0600 AND a|b|c|file2|0600.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  FYI: I had to remove "return hasher.digest()" - this line seemed to allow duplicates to go through on subsequent runs of the program.

Comment: I see. No, you need the line, since that is how you get the checksum. The problem is that it calculates the checksum using the whole line, including the file name, so these lines are treated as different. I am going to edit my code to accomodate.

Comment: Try the version I have now

Answer (score 0):

A couple clues to get you going:

- use a `set()` to keep track of what you have already seen
- the items in the `set` should be strings, and should not include the `filename` and `timestamp` columns

So, for exmaple, loading `olddata` could look like this:

```
olddata = set()
with open(FO) as master:
    for row in csv.reader(master, delimiter = '|'):
        key = '|'.join(row[:3]) # your example has three headers
        olddata.add(key)
```

and when reading new data:

```
        for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(finput, delimiter = '|')):
            key = '|'.join(row)
            if key not in olddata:
                to_append = "Filename" if i==0 else input_file
                data.append(row+[to_append])
                olddata.add(key)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I updated my code to reflect the suggestions you made.  Unfortunately, the code only works once (When the master file is blank).  If I try to run the code when the master file has any data I get _TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found_.  I'm not sure why any line would show up as an int.

Comment: @user3476845: Ah, I see the bug -- `for row in enumerate(csv.reader...` should just be `for row in csv.reader...`.

Answer (score -1):

This is my take on your problem. I defined a function updateMasterFile() to read in a single source file, and the master file. After comparing the two, then write any new data back to the master file.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt

def updateMasterFile(sourceFile, masterFile):
    #open source file and masterFile
    with open(sourceFile, 'r') as pFile, \
         open(masterFile, 'r') as mFile:
        #read all rows into list(newdata) ignore header
        newdata = [row for row in
                   csv.reader(pFile, delimiter="|")][1:]
        #read all rows in to list(oldata) ignore header and last 2 columns
        olddata = [row[:-2] for row in
                   csv.reader(mFile, delimiter="|")][1:]

    # store any new data
    extra = [row for row in newdata if row not in olddata]

    #open master csv in append mode
    with open(masterFile, 'a', newline="") as mFile:
        #define csv writer
        writer = csv.writer(mFile, delimiter ="|")
        #write all 'extra' new data to master file
        for row in extra:
            #write back with source file name (full path) and time stamp
            #you may want to trim the file name and define you own time stamp 
            writer.writerow(row + [sourceFile,
                             dt.strftime(dt.now(),"%y%m%d%H%M%S")])
```

Comment: `olddata` should be a `set()` or the update function will get extremely slow as the masterfile grows.